# Xbee packets giving Incorrect values

Tags: serial, xbee

I am trying to extract analog sample data from an xbee packet that are present in the 20th and th 21st bytes. However after extracting them into the serial monitor the garbage value that is received turns out to be wrong.

Here is the output I receive in the serial monitor :

[image]

First column- lsb
Second column -  msb 
The code for extracting data looks like this:

```
if(Serial.available()>21){

if(Serial.read==0x7e){

for(int i=1;i<19;i++){

byte discard=Serial.read();
}

int analogMSB=Serial.read();

int analogLSB=Serial.read();

int analogReading=analogLSB+(analogMSB*256);
```

When I calculate lsb + msb*256 for the above , I receive negative values as well which is undesirable. Please tell me how I can rectify this issue .

Comment: What is the input voltage - are you sure it's garbage. How do you know the ADC is working correctly at the send end? What's that part of the circuit look like?

Comment: If you're using the 10 or 12 bit ADC on an Arduino (guessing from screen shot) I don't see how you'd get that wide spread of numbers. The first thing I'd do is send say 12345 and see what comes out, it's probably a packet encoding/decoding issue so the code would help.

Comment: At the send end, I have connected an accelerometer(ADXL335) output to pin 19(only using one axis atm) which is configured as ADC.While at the receiver end, I have connected DOUT of xbee to RX of arduino and DIN of xbee to TX of arduino.

Answer (score 1):

If you complain about negative numbers, then you are not correctly accounting for signed versus unsigned arithmetic. Make sure you convert all values to unsigned int, and print them out as unsigned int, to cover the entire 16-bit range.

```
unsigned int x = (unsigned int)lsb + (unsigned int)msb * 256;
printf("%u\n", x);
```

There's a few other troubleshooting tips here, too, like "are you sure these are the right offsets," and "are you sure you have the byte order correct," but let's start with the first thing that's wrong in your post, first!

Answer (score 0):

I see you're looking for 0x7E at the start of a packet which implies you're using API mode. You haven't mentioned the particular XBee module but I believe the packet structure is fairly common between models and here are a few references from the datasheet of the last module I used:

**Escape characters**

> When sending or receiving a UART data frame, specific data values must be escaped (flagged) so they do not interfere with the data frame sequencing. To escape an interfering data byte, insert 0x7D and follow it with the byte to be escaped XOR’d with 0x20.

**Data bytes that need to be escaped:**

- 0x7E – Frame Delimiter
- 0x7D – Escape
- 0x11 – XON
- 0x13 – XOFF

The purpose of that is so that 0x7E will only occur as the frame delimeter. If that and the other mentioned characters occur within the data they will be escaped so you'll end up with two characters in the data stream. Your current code assumes a fixed packet length and that won't be the case when an escaped character is present in the data.

Additionally your code won't resync well when the packet is not the 21 bytes you're expecting so you're probably essentially ending up with random data where you expect the ADC reading.

In my case I wrote a state machine that handled things one character at a time. I reset a buffer when 0x7E was received and used several booleans to keep track of whether the next character was an escaped one or not and used other variables to keep track of the packet progress and whether or not it was complete.

My code was for a different processor and a little different to how you'd do it on an Arduino, but it might give you a pointer in the right direction. Additionally I've found the [xbee-arduino](https://code.google.com/p/xbee-arduino/) and while I've never used it that appears to handle the API mode side of things for you.